# How could I mock a connection in apollo with graphQL to test in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to somehow test a hooked file that uses an Apollo client connection entry and GraphQL:

**See the error:**

> ```
> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(withRouter(Apollo(Connect(SearchResults))))".  Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass  "store" as a prop to "Connect(withRouter(Apollo(Connect(SearchResults))))".
> ```

**My test file:**

A piece of information that I can clarify is that the mock component, in this case I took it from the model that is suggested by react itself.

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import SearchResults from './Searchresults'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/test-utils'
import { graphql,  compose } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

describe('SearchResults', () => {

  const searchBookWithFiltersQuery = gql`query SearchBookWithFiltersQuery( 
      $searchTerm: String!) { 
         ... 
          }`

  const ComposeComponent = compose(
  graphql(searchBookWithFiltersQuery, {
    options: ({ match, location }) => ({
      variables: {
        searchTerm: searchTerm,
        opts:prepare_opts(location.search),
        page: 1
      }
    })
  }),
  connect(mapStateToProps))(SearchResults)

  it('should render the given tourTitle', () => {

    let mocks = []
    const page_filter = mount(
      <Router>
        <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
            <ComposeComponent props={props} />
        </MockedProvider>
      </Router>
    ).find(page_filter.tourTitle)

    expect(page_filter.text()).toBe(page_filter.tourTitle)
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to the problem:

```
import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/test-utils'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { searchBookWithFiltersQuery } from 'api/queries'

describe('SearchResults', () => {
  const customHistory = createBrowserHistory()
  const mockStore = configureMockStore()
  const store = mockStore({
    user: {
          id: 1
    }
  })

  it('should render the given sidebar filter wrapper results', () => {
    let mocks = [
      {
        request: {
          query: searchBookWithFiltersQuery
        },
        result: {
          data: {
             [{"id":1,
                "title":"text 1"
              }, {
              {"id":2,
                "title":"text 2"
              }]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    const search = mount(
      <MockedProvider store={store} mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <Router history={customHistory}>
          <SearchResults />
        </Router>
      </MockedProvider>
    )
    expect(search.containsMatchingElement(<SideBarFilterWrapper />)).toEqual(
      true
    )
  })
```